# How to make Php rest server send reponse back to client

Tags: php, rest

I am making a simple PHP rest service, I am calling this service with CURL here is the code for this

```
//client code example

 $ch = curl_init($URL);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now on Rest Service I am receiving the request and doing the task. Then I have to send the response back.

```
  //server code example

  $xml_post = file_get_contents('php://input');

  $xmlparser = new XMLParser;

  $parsedata = $xmlparser->parse($xml_post);

  $resultobj = new ResultGenerate;

  $result = $resultobj->generate($parsedata);
```

I have no idea how to send the reponse ($result) back.So that $output has the xml string in the end. Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $result
```

is all you need. think about it like this. when using PHP to serve web pages, all you are doing is serving a response to the web browser. You use echo there just like you are using echo here.